# Android: InflateException: Binary XML file line : Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I had gone through several posts over this issue but nothing helped me. The problem is occuring only on large screen devices. Below is stack trace.

**Logcat output**

```
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dzo.seattlesnightlife/com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.StoreDescription}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)  
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:805)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)  
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.StoreDescription.init(StoreDescription.java:195)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.StoreDescription.onCreate(StoreDescription.java:188)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     ... 11 more
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     ... 30 more
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)  
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)  
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1915)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
03-13 15:21:18.863: E/AndroidRuntime(6334):     ... 33 more
```

**XML Layout file**

```
<com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.ui.HeaderBar
    android:id="@+id/baseHeaderBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/baseHeaderBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_sel"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@color/divider_list"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNoData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/no_data"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/baseHeaderBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linImgAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linImgListingPhoto"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="143dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_description"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgListingPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/d_desc"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnFav"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_fav"
                android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_fav" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linPromoTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linImgListingPhoto"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtListingTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_description"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linAddressWebsite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_description"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:id="@+id/relStoreAddress"
                        android:background="@drawable/highlight_rnd_top" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgIcMap"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_map"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_map" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStoreAddress"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcMap"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/arrow_white"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
                        android:background="@color/line" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relStoreContact"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/highlight_mid" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgIcCall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_call"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_call" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStorePhone"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcCall"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/arrow_white"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
                        android:background="@color/line" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:id="@+id/relStoreWeb"
                        android:background="@drawable/highlight_rnd_bottom" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgIcWeb"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_web"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_web" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcWeb"
                            android:id="@+id/txtStoreWebsite"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp" 
                            android:text="@string/visit_web"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/arrow_white"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_white" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linDescInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <include layout="@layout/part_store_sched_tick" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linStoreDescTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_description"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/d_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linStoreDesc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_desc"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.ui.ExpandablePanel
                    android:id="@+id/descPanel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    custom:animationDuration="25"
                    custom:collapsedHeight="80dp"
                    custom:content="@+id/txtDesc"
                    custom:handle="@+id/expand" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@id/txtDesc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view4"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0sp"
                        android:background="@color/line"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@id/expand"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/txt_highlight"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtShowMoreLess"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="@string/show_more"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgMoreLess"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtShowMoreLess"
                            android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                            android:contentDescription="@drawable/arrow_down"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.ui.ExpandablePanel>
            </LinearLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/part_store_info" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linShare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linStoreShareBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtStoreShareTittle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_description"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/d_share"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <include layout="@layout/share_lay_part" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.dzo.seattlesnightlife.ui.FooterBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/baseFooterBar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever I run my app on large screen device or emulator, I get this weired exception. Going through the stack, when I check line no. 29 in XML, it was `android:layout_height` for textView. The line no. of activity, on which app crashed was `setContentView()`. The `OutOfMemoryError` points that there is problem with my drawables. So, I resized my drawables, but nothing helped me. Can't find out what is actual cause of crash.

My [Java file](http://pastie.org/6470102). Sorry couldn't post it here as it exceeded body limit, I tailored it as it had around 5k lines of code.

Ok, when I increased heap size to 48 MB app didn't crashed,but with 16 MB heap, it is still crashing.

Comment: It is failed to inflate your custom views

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it would be better if u change the size of images you using. may be that sizes not capable for that device you using.

Comment: u using it on emulator or your mobile device??

Comment: For large screens, I am running test on emulator. As I don't have large screen device

Comment: Ya you are right. After I scaled down images, every thing worked fine.

Comment: thats great when i run the app on tab its working fine but when i run on phone its crash on inflating class unknown 
this is because of screen size and image size

Answer (score 2):

Your XML error is only the result of the main error : **OutOfMemoryError**

As long as you don't have find the clue to improve your memory management, you'll have theses kind of errors (XML or other)

Your XML is correct, there is no error in it, the line 29 is the "point" where your application were when the OutOfMemoryError occured

Comment: So, what should I do next, shall I go for using MAT?

Comment: You have to think about **force garbage collection**, **Bitmap management** (creation/cache/destruction/max Dimensions)... etc...

Comment: I am not creating any any explicit bitmap. All my drawables are inside resources. So, how can I manage them?

Answer (score 0):

I also think that `OutOfMemoryError` is the decisive part of the `logcat` report. I increased the VM heap of my Android Virtual Device from 16MB to 32 MB. Now it works.

Comment: That's fine, but users are supposed to use the apps on real devices, not on emulator IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem it choose the large layout - larger than screen, and it scaled the bitmaps to it.
then there was out of memory.
i made images smaller in size the background and the buttons and it showed up.
then i saw a too large layout for screen.